# Matlab Fmincon : Setting Constraints with dependency

Tags: matlab, optimization

This may be really simple question for MATLAB fmincon users:

I have a function `Y = AX`, where A is a vector `1 x N` of constants, Y is a scalar constant, and X is a vector `N x 1`; I need to find the optimal values of X such that 
`Y - A*X = 0`. Initial values for `X` come from a `N x 1` vector `X0`. Also

```
X0(1) < X0(2) < ... X0(N)
```

The constraints are:

```
0 <= X(1);
X(1) < X(2);
X(2) < X(3);
...
...
X(N-1) < X(N);
X(N) <= 1;
```

and

```
X0(1) <= X(1);
X0(2) <= X(2);
X0(3) <= X(3);
...
...
X0(N-1) <= X(N-1);
```

My attempt at this problem was:

```
[X, fval] = fmincon(@(X)Y - A*X, X0,[],[],[],[],X0,[X(2:end);1],[],options);
```

I don't think the results I get are correct with this method.
Another attempt was this:

```
[X, fval] = fmincon(@(X)Y - A*X, X0,AA,zeros(N-1,1),[],[],[],[],[],options);
```

where

```
AA = [1 -1 0 0 0 ... N;
      0 1 -1 0 0 ... N;
      .
      .
      0 0 0 0 0 ... 1 -1];  (N-1 Rows)
```

with failure as well.

Any suggestions, hints would be very welcome! I hope I have given enough information regarding the problem.

Following Shai's suggestion I have tried this :

```
[X, fval] = fmincon(@(X) abs(Y - A*X), X0,AA,eps(0)*ones(N-1,1),[],[],X0,[],[],options);
```

But no success. After exactly N iterations the solution converges to X0.
I used the `abs` to get Y - AX to minimize to 0, and X0 in the lower bound to satisfy the conditions `X0(1) < X(1)` etc..

Thanks Shai, using the artificial / dummy objective function, was a great idea. However when I use linprog in the following way :

```
[X, fval] = linprog( -(1:N), AA, -eps(0)*ones(N-1,1), ...
                         A, Y, X0, [], X0, options );
```

I get the problem that Y is a scalar and A is still a `N x 1` vector. and linprog expects Y to be a vector as well. That changes the problem of course. I set the lower bound to X0, upper bound empty (since the inequality constraint takes care of it), and set the initial values to X0. So still not working. Will update if any resolution occurs.

Comment: 1. change `A` to `A.'` so you'll have a single equality constraint with `Y` as its left hand side (a scalar). leave zero and one as lower and upper bounds. You'll have to be more specific about "not working". please leave comments with "@shai" so I'll be notified

Answer (score 1):

I can see no reason why we cannot find an `X` for which `A*X = Y` exactly (there should be enough degrees of freedom for sufficiently large `N`). So instead of making `|A*X-Y|` the objective function to be minimize, I suggest adding `A*X=Y` as a constraint.
Moreover, to encourage `Xi < Xj` for `i<j` I suggest an "artificial" objective function `-(1:N)` that will put larger weight on `Xj` for large `j`.

```
[X, fval] = fmincon( @(X) -(1:N)*X(:), X0, AA, -eps(0)*ones(N-1,1), ...
                                           A, Y, zeros(N,1), ones(N,1), [], options);
```

And while we are at it, why aren't you using [linear programing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) - this should work better than the general purpose `fmincon` as it is tailored for the linear case?

```
[X, fval] = linprog( -(1:N), AA, -eps(0)*ones(N-1,1), ...
                             A, Y, zeros(N,1), ones(N,1), X0, options );
```